# Array Multidimensional from mysql result

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have the following problem I can not achieve the desired format of an array.
I have:

```
while ($ row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($ result))
{
$ alias = $ row ['Alias​​'];
$ read = (int) $ row ['Read'];
$ data [$ alias] [] = $ read;
}
```

and I produce this array:

```
{"310-Amb":[23,24,24,25],
"310-Nev1":[5,5],
"310-Nev2":[6,6],
"310-Nev3":[5,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5,4,4,5,5]}
```

and I need this format:

```
[{"name":"310-Amb","data":[23,24,24,25]},
{"name":"310-Nev1","data":[-74]},
{"name":"310-Nev2","data":[5]},
{"name":"310-Nev3","data":[5,6,6,5,5,4,4,5,4,5,5,5]}]
```

This is my Query

```
SELECT read.Id, read.Fecha, read.Hora, productos.Producto, neveras.Alias, neveras.Min,
neveras.Max, read.Lectura FROM read Inner Join neveras ON read.Nevera_Id = neveras.Id 
Inner Join productos ON neveras.Producto = productos.Id WHERE Hora between
SUBTIME(CURTIME() , '03:00:00') And CURTIME() And read.$TipoClienteX = $IdX 
ORDER BY Alias, Hora Asc
```

Thank you all for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you there.

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc ($result))
{
    $alias = $row['Alias​​'];
    $read = (int) $row['Read'];
    $data[] = array
    (
        'name' => $alias,
        'data' => $read,
    );
}
```

Comment: NOP, The result is: [{"name":"310-Con","data":-74},{"name":"310-Con","data":-74},{"name":"310-Con","data":-72},{"name":"310-Con","data":-73},{"name":"310-Nev3","data":5},{"name":"310-Nev3","data":5},{"name":"310-Nev3","data":4},{"name":"310-Nev3","data":5},{"name":"310-Nev3","data":5},{"name":"310-Nev3","data":5}]

Comment: Your query isn't what I expected it to be then :) Can you post your SQL?

Comment: SELECT read.Id, read.Fecha, read.Hora, productos.Producto, neveras.Alias, neveras.Min,
neveras.Max, read.Lectura FROM read Inner Join neveras ON read.Nevera_Id = neveras.Id 
Inner Join productos ON neveras.Producto = productos.Id WHERE Hora between
SUBTIME(CURTIME() , '03:00:00') And CURTIME() And read.$TipoClienteX = $IdX 
ORDER BY Alias, Hora Asc